# JTextArea doesn't show native-font emoticons

Tags: java, macos, swing

When I print a text that contain emoticons using standard output, the emoticons are shown (pic 1). But when I display the text in JTextArea, the emoticons appear as unidentified chars (pic2). How to solve this?

I'm on OS X & I used the same font for JTextArea as with other editors.

EDIT: I DON'T want to put predefined image emoticons. Rather I want to display the emoticons that are native with fonts. So if I write in any text editor :), I will get an emoticon because the font already has this. I want this to work in JTextArea.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try setting the JTextArea's font to a font in the same family as the font used by your terminal—that is, the terminal font with a different size.  Or the same size if you prefer.

Comment: @VGR this is what I did, but it didn't work :(

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming the string you're rendering is just plain text that contains Unicode emoticon characters from the [miscellaneous symbols range](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2600.pdf) or some similar block - for example, the frowny face is [U+2639](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2639/index.htm)?  If that's not the case, you can disregard the rest of this answer (and consider updating your question to specify what it is you *are* doing).

You've said "it works on the standard output but doesn't work in a JTextArea" - but it looks to me like a different font is being used in your standard output console view than in the JTextArea (look at the "i" character in "Maggie" as an example of how the fonts are different).

It looks as though the font that is being used to render the characters in the console window "knows" how to draw a U+2639, but the font being used in the JTextArea doesn't "know" how to render the character.  The "unidentified chars" that you're seeing are colloquially known as "tofu": whenever a font doesn't know how to draw a character, it draws the "[white square](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25a1/index.htm)" character instead.  Try the API [canDisplay()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#canDisplay%28char%29) method for figuring out if a specific font "knows" how to display a specific character.

Exactly what font are you setting on the JTextArea and how?
Consider posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) - I do have access to an OS X environment at the moment so I might be able to help; and of course there's a hojillion other people that can probably help you out to if they could see clearly what you're doing.

Comment: +1 List of available fonts could be used here. For each font just  canDisplay() should be called passing the desired char(s). When suitable font found it can be used for the JTextArea.

Answer (score 1):

Use JTextPane. Set content type to text/html. And place appropriate html via setText();

That's about local images http://java-sl.com/tip_local_images.html

And this one about smiles http://java-sl.com/tip_autoreplace_smiles.html

Comment: I need to keep adding text to the place where the text should be displayed. So I call append(). But I'm not sure if it's good to keep calling setText() on JTextPane.

Comment: I just tried it ... this won't be scalable as I keep adding text

Comment: Oh and I want to show native font emoticons, not pre-defined images!